# How to create SystemTrayMenu from loop expression

Tags: rust, tauri

With my php development experience, I'm used to calling and modifying data in loops, but that doesn't seem to work with rust.

Can someone help me see how the following code should be modified to compile and get the correct result?

**Add dependency to Cargo.toml** :

```ini
[build-dependencies]
tauri-build = { version = "1.2", features = [] }

[dependencies]
tauri = { version = "1.2", features = ["icon-png", "shell-open", "system-tray"] }
```

**Code**:

```rust
use tauri::{CustomMenuItem, SystemTray, SystemTrayMenu, SystemTrayMenuItem, SystemTraySubmenu};

pub fn menu() -> SystemTray {
    let tray_menu = SystemTrayMenu::new()
        .add_native_item(SystemTrayMenuItem::Separator)
        .add_submenu(SystemTraySubmenu::new(
            "Setting",
            SystemTrayMenu::new()
                .add_item(CustomMenuItem::new(
                    "edit_config".to_string(),
                    "Edit config",
                ))
                .add_item(CustomMenuItem::new(
                    "reload_config".to_string(),
                    "Reload config",
                ))
                .add_item(CustomMenuItem::new("quit".to_string(), "Quit")),
        ));

    for i in 0..55 {
        let si = i.to_string();
        &tray_menu.add_item(CustomMenuItem::new(
            "id_".to_string() + &si,
            "m".to_string() + &si,
        ));
    }
    SystemTray::new().with_menu(tray_menu)
}
```

**Error**:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `tray_menu`
  --> src/tray.rs:24:10
   |
6  |     let tray_menu = SystemTrayMenu::new()
   |         --------- move occurs because `tray_menu` has type `SystemTrayMenu`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
22 |     for i in 0..55 {
   |     -------------- inside of this loop
23 |         let si = i.to_string();
24 |         &tray_menu.add_item(CustomMenuItem::new(
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
   |
help: consider cloning the value if the performance cost is acceptable
   |
24 |         &tray_menu.clone().add_item(CustomMenuItem::new(
   |                   ++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

I have try edit the code, but not executed correctly:

```rust
       &tray_menu.clone().add_item(CustomMenuItem::new(
            "id_".to_string() + &si,
            "m".to_string() + &si,
        ));
```

Comment: What library does `SystemTray` come from? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I have added more details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_item()` consumes the `SystemTrayMenu`, and you cannot use it again.

However, it also returns it, which means you can rebind it:

```rust
pub fn menu() -> SystemTray {
    let mut tray_menu = SystemTrayMenu::new()
        .add_native_item(SystemTrayMenuItem::Separator)
        .add_submenu(SystemTraySubmenu::new(
            "Setting",
            SystemTrayMenu::new()
                .add_item(CustomMenuItem::new(
                    "edit_config".to_string(),
                    "Edit config",
                ))
                .add_item(CustomMenuItem::new(
                    "reload_config".to_string(),
                    "Reload config",
                ))
                .add_item(CustomMenuItem::new("quit".to_string(), "Quit")),
        ));

    for i in 0..55 {
        let si = i.to_string();
        tray_menu = tray_menu.add_item(CustomMenuItem::new(
            "id_".to_string() + &si,
            "m".to_string() + &si,
        ));
    }
    SystemTray::new().with_menu(tray_menu)
}
```